# Unable to run shell script inside from jenkins pipeline

Tags: linux, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, openstack-nova

I am trying to run following shell script from jenkins pipeline but its giving error.

```
/bin/openstack image create Abhay_Centos_6_8_img_V7 --disk-format vhd --min-disk 40 --min-ram 1024 --volume "71c8532d-4fc0-42d4-a534-7b368e4804cb" --unprotected --property __os_type=Linux --property __platform=Linux --property __os_version="CentOS linux 6.8" --force
```

Error:

```
/bin/openstack image create Abhay_Centos_6_8_img_V7 --disk-format vhd --min-disk 40 --min-ram 1024 --volume 71c8532d-4fc0-42d4-a534-7b368e4804cb --unprotected --property __os_type=Linux --property __platform=Linux --property '__os_version=CentOS linux 6.8' --force
Uploading data and using container are not allowed at the same time
Build step 'Conditional step (single)' marked build as failure
[BFA] Scanning build for known causes...
[BFA] No failure causes found
[BFA] Done. 0s
Finished: FAILURE
[BFA] Scanning build for known causes...
[BFA] No failure causes found
[BFA] Done. 0s
[BFA] Scanning build for known causes...
[BFA] No failure causes found
[BFA] Done. 0s
```

But same script is running fine if I run shell script manually on server.

Comment: abhay, can you post your jenkins pipeline conf also.

Comment: https://pastebin.com/raw/7gesMJn3

Comment: https://pastebin.com/raw/V58sMmZ4

Answer (score 0):

Very late answer but I just met the problem and solved it, so let's share a solution :

after inspecting Openstack code, it appears that 'openstack image create' checks tty status : it needs a tty (even if you create from a volume), that cron or jenkins may not provide. So you need to "fake" a tty to execute the command :

example in bash :

```
faketty() {
    script -qefc "$(printf "%q " "$@")"
}
faketty openstack image create --volume ${VOLUME_NAME} ${IMAGE_NAME}
```

Enjoy